# How to separate individual object from nested tree structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

I am having a structure like this

```
var arr = [
  {
    "text": "Parent 1",
    "id"  : "1",
    "nodes": [
      {
        "text": "Child 1",
        "id"  : "2",
        "parentid"  : "1",
        "nodes": [
          {
            "text": "Grandchild 1",
            "id"  : "4",
            "parentid"  : "2",
          },
          {
            "text": "Grandchild 2",
             "id"  : "8",
            "parentid"  : "2",
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "text": "Child 2",
        "id"  : "10",
        "parentid"  : "1",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": "Parent 2",
    "id"  : "19",
    //no parent id
  }
];
```

I want to convert like this -

```
var arr=[
{
     "text":"text1",
     "id"  :"1",
     //no parent id
 },
{
     "text":"text2",
     "id"  :"2",
     "idParent":"1"
 },
{
     "text":"text3",
     "id"  :"3",
     "idParent":"2"
 },
{
     "text":"text4",
     "id"  :"4",
     "idParent":"1"
 },
{
     "text":"text5",
     "id"  :"5",
      //no parent id
 },
];
```

How can I do this in Javascript? I want to have a conversion from nested tree object to individual objects. I am not sure how to recursive pass thorough the array of objects to get the individual ones.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Create a new array A. For all objects in Array add the object to A and check If object has nodes and call the method again for nodes. Don't forget to delete the nodes on the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of `recursion`:

```js
const arr = [ { "text": "Parent 1", "id" : "1", "nodes": [ { "text": "Child 1", "id" : "2", "parentid" : "1", "nodes": [ { "text": "Grandchild 1", "id" : "4", "parentid" : "2", }, { "text": "Grandchild 2", "id" : "8", "parentid" : "2", } ] }, { "text": "Child 2", "id" : "10", "parentid" : "1", } ] }, { "text": "Parent 2", "id" : "19", }];

const getFlatData=arr=>arr.flatMap(({nodes, ...rest})=>nodes ? 
  [{...rest}, ...getFlatData(nodes)] : ({...rest}));

console.log(getFlatData(arr));
```